# Why is new Date("CNE-TEST-0000056") NOT invalid date?

Tags: javascript, node.js, date

I am working on report generation module and I am checking if the value in each record a date for formatting purpose.

```
var records = [{
    recordNumber : "CNE-TEST-00056", 
    name : "Test Name 1",
    createdAt: "2018-03-12"
  }, {
    recordNumber : "CNE-TEST-00057", 
    name : "Test Name 2",
    createdAt: "2018-01-26T18:30:00.000Z"
  }];
```

These are the records in my report. The keys in each object will be dynamic and I want to know what type they are of actually.

I am trying to know type `Date` by using function below.

```
function isDate(date){
    var date1 = new Date(date);

    if(isNaN(date1.getFullYear()) || date1.getFullYear() == 1970){
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

When I do `new Date("CNE-TEST-00056")` it should technically return me `Invalid Date` and `new Date("CNE-TEST-00056").getFullYear()` should return `NaN`. But it returns `Sun Jan 01 1956 00:00:00 GMT+0530`.

How can I make it say `"CNE-TEST-00056"` is not a date.

Comment: maybe upgrade to some better wrappers like moment.js

Comment: @johnSmith But before formatting with moment.js I should know that the field I am using is a date.

Comment: @johnSmith `moment("CNE-TEST-000056")._isValid` this gives me true.

Comment: It's trying hard to get a date from your input and "year 1956" is the only assumption it's able to make. Using `Date()` constructor to parse dates from strings is unreliable and inconsistent (no matter how popular it is) but it's particularly useless to validate dates.

Comment: If using the built-in parser, the only way to validate the date values is to also manually parse the string and compare the results (a library might help with that but it’s not necessary).

Answer (score 0):

For you specific example, you can use a little bit of a hacky way to determine it.

Code snippet -> https://snipp.ly/xo2ib7Bi

```
function isDate(date){
    var date1 = new Date(date);

    if(isNaN(date1.getFullYear()) || date1.getFullYear() == 1970 || date.replace(/[^A-Z]/gi, "").length > 2){
      return false;
    }

   return true;
 }
```

This adds an extra check to your if statement that replaces everything that isn't a alphabetic letter and gets the count. So when it does that for CNE-TEST-0057, the count is 7 while for 2018-01-26T18:30:00.000Z the count is 2 for 'T' and 'Z'. This isn't full proof as something like C-T-00057 would pass as true. I don't think there is a way to do this with javascript's Date parsing, I believe this requires an extra check on your data has I have showed in the example above

Comment: Please post runnable snippets here, not elsewhere. Links rot. This also doesn’t seem to be a very good test. Is “July 23, 1970” an invalid date?